# which is better if you want to come out form function ? return or return false

Tags: javascript

I have two function for example :

```
function fn1(){
    return false;
}

function fn2(){
    return;
}

alert(fn1());
alert(fn2());
```

return will give you `"undefined"` and return false will give you boolean `"false"` what should i prefer and why ??
 **both will come out from the function but what to choose and what should not**

**Better as javascript standard point of you**

Comment: Is the return value used for anything?

Comment: It depends on the purpose of the function.

Comment: @AlexChar no i guess coz i know the difference but i want to know which is better..

Comment: well `return;`  means `return undefined;`

Comment: @deceze no.. just wanted to know which is better for the purpose which i am looking for

Comment: @AnirbanN ya i know i already mention that.. my question is which is better for standard point of view

Comment: @FelixKling a better javascript standard

Comment: If your purpose is to come out from function then return is better

Comment: Javascript is pretty irrelevant, it's the same in most languages. If you need a specific return value, use a return value. Otherwise don't.

Comment: IMO it depends on the signature of the function. If the function is supposed to return a Boolean, of course you should return false. If it's not supposed to refine anything, it would be `rerurn;` or simply nothing.

Comment: purpose of function is to return somthing rite ? so return undefined is good and return false

Comment: Well, yeah, in a mathematical sense a function always produces a value. But in JavaScript, "functions" are used as functions or as procedures (e.g. event handlers). Whether to return something or not depends on the actual use case. Of course you can always follow the rule to *not* return something if not required. This avoids giving the false impression that the return value is meaningful. But that's more or less obvious I hope?

Answer (score 0):

You should return whatever you need. 
If you don't need an specific answer just "return", if you want know the result of the function you must return a value (boolean or not).

Comment: will undefined look better instead of return false ?

Comment: You should read previous answer if care about how it look.